# How do you end a method from code in another method?

Tags: c#

How do I end a method with logic in another method? It seems return only works in the method it is in.

```
private void BeAmazing (int number) {
   HandleNumber(number);
   Debug.Log("number is 3 or less");
}

private void HandleNumber(int number) {
   if (number > 3) {
      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: Of course `return` only works in the method it is in. You're `return`ing from that method into the method that called it. That is what `return` is for (sometimes with a value/object).

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean - you don't end a method from outside a method, you wait for it to return a value. Well, you *could* do something like have the first method modify the state of some shared object, and the second method could be written to exit if the state is modified in a particular way. But that's not typically done.

Comment: You can return a boolean value you can check at the caller side with a simple `if()` for a "smooth" exit or you can throw an exception for a "hard" exit.

Comment: It might be helpful if you described a little more high-level detail about what you're trying to accomplish. There is certainly a good way to do it.

Comment: [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return): "The return statement terminates execution of the method in which it appears and returns control to the calling method. It can also return an optional value. If the method is a void type, the return statement can be omitted."

Comment: This sounds line an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377). Instead of telling us what you want to do, tell us what your goal is. That is; pretend you really could “end a method from code in another method”; what is that going to win you?

Comment: It's also worth noting that your `HandleNumber` function uses an `if` statement to check a condition, and if it's true, `returns` from the function.  If it's not true, then, since there is no other code in the function, it will simply return.  Your function is essentially empty - and, in fact, in a release build, I'd be surprised if it isn't optimized away.  as @DourHighArch asks, what are you really trying to do

Comment: Well you could throw an `Exception` but using exceptions in this way for program flow control is kinda naughty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner function should return a result indicating whether it was successful in doing whatever it is supposed to do, like this:

```
private void BeAmazing (int number) {
  if (!HandleNumber(number)) {
    Debug.Log("number is 3 or less");
  }
}

private bool HandleNumber(int number) {
  if (number > 3) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to guess a bit, as your description was insufficient. But I guess that FunctionA calls FunctionB - propably in some form of loop - and that in certain cases things that happen in FunctionB should also cancel the loop in FunctionA, thus ending FunctionA.

The primary way for this is throwing Exceptions. Exceptions will just plow through all brackets, until they find catch block. And the last one is in the Framework itself. There are [two](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) [articles](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET) on excetpion handling, that a link often.

However one rule the mention is to not throw exceptions in situations that are not exceptional. And this case might not be exceptional. Well, for those cases there are out parameters:

```
void FunctionA(){
  bool continueLoop = true;
  while(continueLoop){
     FunctionB(out continueLoop);
  }
}

void FunctionB(out bool continueLoop){
  //Set the bool, for out parameters this will change it back in FunctionA
  continueLoop = false;
}
```

Of course there is also the way more common case of Recursion, where FunctionA and FunctionB are either the same, or B keeps calling itself. This is often better then using a loop like this.

Comment: Rather than using an `out` parameter, you might consider using a return value.  A `void` function with an `out` parameter isn't what I (as the reader) would expect.

Comment: @Flydog57 It seemed rather clear he wanted the return value of the function for something else. I only used void to make the example code easier.

Answer (score 0):

Robert McKee has got the question covered, but here are two little examples how 
`HandleNumber` could communicate with `BeAmazing` using an exception.

*Please note that an `if` is the simplest solution here. The examples below are just to show another possibility.*

## Example 1

Task: Print the message if `number` is  3 or less without modifying `BeAmazing`.

```
private void BeAmazing (int number) 
{
    HandleNumber(number);
    Debug.WriteLine("number is 3 or less");
}

private void HandleNumber(int number) {
   if (number > 3) {
      throw new Exception("Number is > 3");
   }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var p = new Program();
    try 
    { 
        p.BeAmazing(5);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex ) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    p.BeAmazing(3);
```

```
Number is > 3
number is 3 or less
```

## Example 2

Task: Make `BeAmazing` print different messages if `number` is >3 or not without modifying the signature of `HandleNumber`.

```
private void BeAmazing (int number) 
{
    try 
    {
        HandleNumber(number);
        Console.WriteLine($"This number is amazing");
    } 
    catch( Exception ex ) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void HandleNumber(int number) {
   if (number > 3) {
      return;
   }
   throw new Exception("Number is 3 or less");
}


public static void Main()
{
    var p = new Program();
    p.BeAmazing(5);
    p.BeAmazing(3);
}
```

```
This number is amazing
Number is 3 or less
```